# gRPC support for Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, grpc, xamarin.mac

I'm currently trying to add grpc to my Xamarin.Mac app. I'm able to add the nuget packages but while compiling i'm getting the following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_gprsharp_convert_clock_type", referenced from:
         -u command line option
      "_gprsharp_free", referenced from:
         -u command line option
      "_gprsharp_inf_future", referenced from:
         -u command line option
...
...
```

Comment: which nuget package? would that be better asked of the developer?

Comment: `Grpc, Grpc.Core, Grpc.Tools, Google.Protobuf`

Comment: From here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.21.0/src/csharp/README.md#prerequisites it seems they support it

Comment: Consider filing an issue at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/new but please make sure to provide exact instructions how to reproduce.